# How to deserialize a property with a dash (“-”) in its name with NewtonSoft JsonConvert?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

We have a JSON object with one of the object having a dash in its name. Ex below.

```
{
    "veg": [
        {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "Vegetables",
            "count": "25"
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "name": "Dal",
            "count": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": "5",
            "name": "Rice",
            "count": "8"
        },
        {
            "id": "7",
            "name": "Breads",
            "count": "6"
        },
        {
            "id": "9",
            "name": "Meals",
            "count": "3"
        },
        {
            "id": "46",
            "name": "Extras",
            "count": "10"
        }
    ],
    "non-veg": [
        {
            "id": "25",
            "name": "Starters",
            "count": "9"
        },
        {
            "id": "30",
            "name": "Gravies",
            "count": "13"
        },
        {
            "id": "50",
            "name": "Rice",
            "count": "4"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can we deserialize this json?

Comment: Not a duplicate. This question seeks to solve a specific and distinct problem. One that I had, by the way, so I'm kind of invested in this.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can achieve this by using DataContractJsonSerializer

```
[DataContract]
public class Item
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "count")]
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class ItemCollection
{
    [DataMember(Name = "veg")]
    public IEnumerable<Item> Vegetables { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "non-veg")]
    public IEnumerable<Item> NonVegetables { get; set; }
}
```

now you can deserialize it with something like this:

```
string data;

// fill the json in data variable

ItemCollection collection;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(data)))
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ItemCollection));
    collection = (ItemCollection)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
}
```

Comment: Can I define `DataMember` only for the property containing the dash and leave the rest as it is?

Comment: You need to add DataMember to every property you want to be serialized, however you may not specify the name if the name of the property is good enough.

Comment: For those wondering, `using System.Runtime.Serialization;`

Answer (score 99):

To answer the question on how to do this WITH NewtonSoft, you would use the JsonProperty property attribute flag.

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName="non-veg")]
public string nonVeg { get; set; }
```

Comment: For VB use: <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="non-veg")>

Answer (score 5):

Based on Jerry's answer you can do it this way using `System.Text.Json.Serialization`:

```cs
[JsonPropertyName("non-veg")]
public string nonVeg { get; set; }
```

Comment: That's the one that worked for me (not using Newtonsoft in my current project).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JObject.Parse` (included in newtonsoft) to grab any properties even if they have special characters.

```
JObject result = JObject.Parse(json);
Console.WriteLine(result["non-veg"][0]["name"].ToString());
```

Comment: Yes, if we don't use a class for deserializing, we can access the value with key value like jsonresult["key"]