# JSON property names contains illegal characters, how to convert to C# model?

Tags: c#, json

**Question Background:**

I am calling an API that I have no control over. It is return a JSON response which contains property names with symbols such as '@'.

**The Issue:**

This is an example of the JSON returned:

```
{"@currencyId":"USD", "__value__":"7.85"}
```

I am converting this to a C# POCO such as:

```
public Class Obj
{
   public string @currencyId {get; set;}
   public string __value__ {get; set;}
}
```

Even before I am able to use any library such as JSON.NET this is causing errors.

What is the best method to convert the response to property names that can be used with my C# POCO?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [How can I parse a JSON string that would cause illegal C# identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24536533).  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24536739) is the one that applies in your case, since you have a fixed schema.  See also [How to deserialize a property with a dash (“-”) in it's name with NewtonSoft JsonConvert?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14753113) which includes an answer for `DataContractJsonSerializer`.  But the specific answer will depend on the serializer you are using.  Is it Json.NET?

Comment: Note however that if you are using `JavaScriptSerializer` that remapping of property names via attributes is not supported.  see [JavaScriptSerializer - custom property name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32487483/3744182) for details.