# how to deserialise json string when the json contains a - character on the name

Tags: asp.net, json, deserialization

I'm being asked to read in orders from json same format as http://jsonapi.org/

Here is a sample, note that some of the names have "-" in them for example: `order-totals`, `order-products`

```
"data": [
    {
        "type": "orders",
        "attributes": {
            "customer_address_name": "testTestmann",
            "customer_address_company": "",
            "customer_address_zipcode": "9022",
            "customer_address_state": "uk",
        },
        "relationships": {
            "customer": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "customers",
                    "id": "1"
                }
            },
            "order-status": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "order-status",
                    "id": "3"
                }
            },
            "order-totals": {
                "links": {
                    "related": "test2"
                }
            },
            "order-products": {
                "links": {
                    "related": "test1"
                }
            },
            "order-tags": {
                "links": {
                    "related": "test3"
                }
            },
            "order-status-history": {
                "links": {
                    "related": "test4"
                }
            }
        },
```

Here is the code I use to deserialise:

```
Dim jsonOrders As String = jutils.GetJsonText(shopurl, shoptoken)
Dim obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of MYS_Orders.MyStore_Orders)(jsonOrders)
```

This works fine on all attributes apart from the ones with names that include a "-" so of course `OrderStatus` does not deserialise.

This is what the objects look like :

```
Public Class OrderStatus
    Public Property data As Data
End Class

Public Class OrderTotals
    Public Property links As Links
End Class

Public Class OrderProducts
    Public Property links As Links
End Class
```

How can I name the objects with a "-" character so the deserialization works?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deserialize a property with a dash (“-”) in it's name with NewtonSoft JsonConvert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753113/how-to-deserialize-a-property-with-a-dash-in-its-name-with-newtonsoft-jso)

Comment: Not sure if duplicate. Looks like Visual Basic code, not C#.

Comment: its similar and can see the solution for property but not for the object name...how is this done in c# or vb.net ?

Comment: The duplicate applies. It is the same issue and the answer can be applied to this question. Use the JsonProperty attribute.